# how to track Facebook Comment box plugin in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails 3.2 Application and I use this FB plugin for comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Can I track the comments into my Rails Application? E.g. via FB JSON API? The best would be if I get all urls of my site, where comments are ... is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution from Facebook API documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/